# Desativar o Debug Mode no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, debug

### **Problema**

Tenho um template no WordPress, que estava funcionando normalmente. Em dado momento, sem que eu alterasse nada, o seguinte erro começou a aparecer no topo da página:

```
 Debug Mode On
 Array ( [page] => 0 [ad_listing] => [..]
```

### **O que pretendo?**

No momento não estou muito preocupado com o erro, pois poderei resolvê-lo depois mas, por ora gostaria de desativar o modo de *debug*, mas não estou conseguindo.

**O que já tentei?**

1. Adicionar `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` no wp_config.php
2. Deletar a linha `wp_debug_mode();` no wp_settings.php
3. Procurar sobre `desativar debug mode no wordpress`, mas não achei nada que ajude.
4. Usar `define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', false );` e `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` porém um novo erro aparece:

   ```
     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$table_prefix' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/barie742/public_html/recarga-de-toner-em-sao-paulo/wp-config.php on line 66
   ```

E na linha 66 está: `$table_prefix  = 'wp_';`

> **@EDIT**
>
> O erro estava acontecendo pela falta do `;`, porém mesmo após
>   adiciona-las o `DEBUG MODE ON` continua aparecendo.

### *Resumo*

Apenas gostaria de desativar o `Debug Mode` no Wordpress.

Comment: Já tentou usar define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', false );     ou define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);  ??

Comment: Exato! Desculpe não dar mais detalhes, estou pelo o celular.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta @GiovanniBernini, com o novo erro

Comment: O erro aparece no topo da página, porem continua carregando a página normalmente? o `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` deu o mesmo erro que o `define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', false );` ?

Comment: Sim @GiovanniBernini, no topo da página, ela funciona tudo normal, o link da página é http://barietoner.com.br/recarga-de-toner-em-sao-paulo/

Comment: E ambas funções de definição não mudaram nada, poderia ser alguma função no próprio template que ativa o debug?

Comment: Estranho! Tenta colocar um `@ini_set ( 'display_errors', 0);` caso não for, mande seu `wp_config.php` sem os dados de conexão.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37918/discussion-between-victor-gomes-and-giovanni-bernini).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solução:**

Esta solução que vou colocar abaixo não é uma das melhores, porém como o `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`, `define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', false );` e `define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` não funcionaram, eu resolveria assim:

Adicionando esse código CSS no style principal.

```
.debug {
    display: none!important;
}
```